# I am trying to bring selector(Formula CD) for filter data in formula master screen,

Tags: acumatica

FormulaID is the identity field and it's new developed screen, but I am not able to get the selector. I have tried all the ways that I know to achieve that:

1. Maintaining parent and child relationships
2. Dataview with BQL Query

### Below are the definitions of the FormulaID and FormulaCD from DAC:

```
#region FormulaID
public abstract class formulaID : PX.Data.IBqlField
{
}
protected int? _FormulaID;

[PXDBIdentity(IsKey =true)]
[PXUIField(Enabled = false)]
public virtual int? FormulaID
{
    get
    {
        return this._FormulaID;
    }
    set
    {
        this._FormulaID = value;
    }
#endregion

#region FormulaCD
public abstract class formulaCD : PX.Data.IBqlField
{
}
protected string _FormulaCD;

[PXDBString(30,IsUnicode = true)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Formula ID", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
[PXSelector(typeof(Search<TSFormula.formulaCD>),
       typeof(TSFormula.descr),SubstituteKey = typeof(TSFormula.formulaCD), ValidateValue = false)]
public virtual string FormulaCD
{
    get
    {
        return this._FormulaCD;
    }
    set
    {
        this._FormulaCD = value;
    }
}
#endregion
```

Comment: Can any suggest me to get  the selector

Comment: Could you try setting IsKey=true to the FormulaCD instead of FormulaID field ?

Comment: yes I gave IsKey = true @cbetabeta

Answer (score 1):

In my example below, the PXDBIdentity integer field is not enabled and not visible.  The String field is marked isKey=true with the PXSelector described.  The ASPX page markup offers the px:PXSelector tag for the String field as shown:

```
      <px:PXSelector ID="edContractNumber" runat="server" DataField="ContractNumber"
            AutoRefresh="True" DataSourceID="ds" NullText="<NEW>">
            <GridProperties FastFilterFields="ShortName">
                <Columns>
                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="ContractNumber" Width="90px"></px:PXGridColumn>
                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="ShortName" Width="120px"></px:PXGridColumn>
                </Columns>
            </GridProperties>
        </px:PXSelector>
```

Here are the DAC fields:

```
    #region ContractID
    public abstract class contractID : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    [PXDBIdentity()]
    [PXDefault(0)]
    [PXUIField(Visible = false, Enabled = false)]
    public virtual int? ContractID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    #endregion

    #region ContractNumber
    public abstract class contractNumber : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    [PXDBString(IsKey = true)]
    [PXDefault()]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search3<MyDAC.contractNumber,
                OrderBy<Desc<MyDAC.contractID>>>),
        new Type[] {           
        typeof(MyDAC.shortName),
        typeof(MyDAC.contractNumber)},
        DirtyRead = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Contract Number", Required = true)]
    public virtual string ContractNumber { get; set; }
    #endregion
```